# how to take complete control of zend2 form styling?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I was following this guide (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html) and the "zend" way of writing form fields is something like:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Title',
        ),
    ));
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<label>
<span>Surname/Faculty</span>
<input type="text" value="" name="title">
</label>
```

I can supply "class" parameter to the form field but supplying "class" to the label does nothing. I also want to include a "br" tag at the end of the "label" tag.

any ideas on how to make it work? I've looked at recent examples and tutorials (seems decorators have been phased out of zend2?) but I can't find what I'm looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably now use some view helpers to help you render the form in your view script.

What you can also do is get the form elements and render them yourself like this

```
<?php
    $element = $form->get('ElementName'); // In your case 'title'
?>
<label><?php echo $element->label;?></label> <br />
<?php echo $element->input; ?>
```

This should output something like:

```
 <label>Title</label> <br />
 <input type="text" value="" name="title">
```

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan